# I can't find where textarea margin is

Tags: html, css, textarea

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6M34Ej8NH0hd2xDNlJyeEh1ZE0/edit?usp=sharing

http://jsfiddle.net/54end/

```
<textarea name="incomes" id="in" rows="2" cols="88" class="form-control" rows='1' style="width: 100px; margin-bottom:0px; resize: none;">1</textarea>
```

▲ this is the part of my project..

As you see the page, My textarea has extra padding under it but I can't find the source of it.

Please someone fix this..

Comment: post your relevant code here, rather than posting download link.

Comment: the link doesn't work for me, can you make a jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: Oh... I don't know how to do it..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/54end/

Comment: you should be more specific. there are 3 textareas in your code. which one are you talking about?

Comment: you may find 'test' and 'save screen'button and two textboxs next them.

Comment: Their lines are not straight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem relates to vertical alignment.

The `textarea`'s default value for the `display` property is `inline-block`, and the default value for the `vertical-align` property is `baseline`. Change it to `middle`, for example, and compare the difference.

**Further reading:**

- [`vertical-align` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)
- [What is Vertical Align?](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/) (an article that explores the different values)

Comment: In the JSFiddle example the vertical alignment isn't set for textareas, so it falls back to the default, which is 'baseline' (the baseline of the text). Since there is padding on .btn-lg, the baseline of the text is above the perceived baseline of the line.

Comment: Here's a nice article exploring the different vertical alignment values: http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

Answer (score 2):

You have two `rows` attribute on your textarea, maybe try to just set one `row` attribute to `1`?

```
<textarea name="incomes" id="in" rows="1" cols="88" class="form-control" style="width: 100px; margin-bottom:0px; resize: none;">1</textarea>
```

Edit: there is also a `height: 42px` on your textarea, maybe it's what cause the extra padding at the bottom?